# Object.CompareTo(Object) for unknown data type

Tags: c#, object, compareto

I am trying to compare objects in an `object[]` that are of a single type (unknown at runtime). They are of `System.string`, `int`, `decimal`, `Datetime`, or `bool` types.

Is there a way to compare two of these objects to determine if one is greater or less than another without having to cast them into their appropriate type first?

Comment: You have at least to cast them to IComparable and then use CompareTo .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types in question all implement IComparable, so, if being able to compare elements is an intrinsic requirement of your array, you could declare it as an `IComparable[]` instead.

Comment: Hah, You were 3 seconds faster ;-)

Answer (score 2):

All of those types implement `IComparable` interface, so you can cast your objects to `IComparable` (or just keep an `IComparable[]` array instead of `object[]`). Then you can use
`CompareTo(object x)` method.

Answer (score 1):

All of the types you mention implements `IComparable`, so you can use `IComparable.CompareTo`. As an example:

```
object[] ints = new object[] { 2, 1, 3};
object n = 2;
var compareResults = ints.OfType<IComparable>().Select(c => c.CompareTo(n));
```